# Is it possible to control particles with shader's texture?

Tags: particles, shaders, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

I have this shader where gradient goes through an object and changing its color to red. I control this animation with an empty.

I would like to add particles to the yellow part. Is it somehow possible to transfer the gradient data from the shader to particle texture controls? Or is there some other way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You need to bake an image texture sequence. The baked image sequence can be used to control the density of the particles. Or use a completely different approach with Geometry Nodes. Calculate the gradient in GN and place the "particles" (point instances). Then use the gradient in the shader to create the colors. Or manipulate a vertex group and use this for the density of the particles.